# using gstreamer or ffmpeg to create hsync and vsync video effect using just terminal commands

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I'm trying to find a way to create a vsync / hsync effect *by just typing commands into the terminal*.  Can gstreamer or ffmpeg do this?

Example:  I have an image and I want it to repeatedly **scroll up** and / or **scroll to the side**.
See example of animated vertical gif image below

[image: Hsync]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 (linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vertical scroll,

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in.png -filter_complex "[0][0]vstack,crop=iw:ih/2:0:t*ih/2/p" -t p out.mp4
```

where `p` is the duration of the scroll from top to bottom. For seamless looping, you'll have to trim out the last frame. To do that, use `-t p-0.04` instead.

For horizontal scroll,

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in.png -filter_complex "[0][0]hstack,crop=iw/2:ih:t*iw/2/p:0" -t p out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a way with GStreamer:

You can use the frei0r plugin library which features the frei0r-filter-nosync0r element:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! frei0r-filter-nosync0r hsync=0.5 ! autovideosink
```

The property of this element is controllable which mean you can modify it over stream-time. (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/dparams.html)

For the vertical de-synchronization, you can rotate the image before and after applying this filter. For this purpose, two GStreamer elements comes to my mind: `videoflip` and 'rotate' with angle of pi/2. Rotate offers more possibilities since it allow you to specify the angle you want the image to be rotated.